# How can I use protected variables to good effect in abstract classes?

Tags: java

I suppose what I'm asking is what the best practice is. Take this example:

```
public abstract class GameObject {

protected Vector2 position;

    protected GameObject(Vector2 position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    protected Vector2 getPosition() {
        ...
    }

    protected void setPosition(Vector2 position) {
        ... 
    }
...
}
```

If we have a `GameObject` abstract class that `Player` extends, should I be setting all of my fields (e.g. speed, position) and methods in `GameObject` to be protected?

What's the nice way of doing this?

Comment: You should use them as little as possible, preferably never.

Answer (score 0):

In order to comply with Data Encapsulation, a good practice is to keep your fields private/protected and your methods public.